# Проверить input на значение

Tags: javascript, html5, input

Есть задачка, проверить `<input type="text" name="b1" id="right_answer">` на строку, то есть пользователю нужно будет вбить ответ, без пробелов ничего сверх сложного, но у меня получился затуп на стадии проверки в js. Написал я такой код на проверку

```js
function Check_Radio(){
var count = 0
var ex1 = document.getElementById("right1");
if (ex1 == "test"){
 count++;
 }
  console.log(count);
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="b1" id="right1">
```

Не могу понять как тут сравнить верно. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: document.getElementById("right1").value

Comment: а с чем сравнивать??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример небольшой

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', check)

function check() {
  if (this.value == 'test') {
    console.log('succes')
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
  // Или более короткая запись (Тернарный оператор)
  // this.value == 'test' ? console.log('succes'): console.log('error') 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="b1" id="input">
```

Comment: Спасибо, замечательно работает. Немного забыл за eventlistener

Comment: @ДмитрийКотовский всегда пожалуйста ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inp");

input.addEventListener("input", function(){
  console.log(this.value === "text" ? "true" : "false");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Заглупил немного